# B.A.T.M.A.N. working with cable, not with wireless

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm creating a mesh network with [B.A.T.M.A.N.](http://www.open-mesh.org/).

The version is *2011.4.0* in host A, *2012.3.0* in host B. I've setup the network as [explained here](http://www.open-mesh.org/projects/batman-adv/wiki/Quick-start-guide).

I can ping `bat0` interfaces if the connection is done with ethernet cable:

```
# Host A
ifconfig eth2 mtu 1528
batctl if add eth2
ifconfig bat0 192.168.6.6

# Host B
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1528
batctl if add eth0
ifconfig bat0 192.168.6.7
ping 192.168.6.6 ## Ping ok
```

If i switch to wireless adhoc, without security, this doesn't work.

```
# Host A
ifconfig eth1 mtu 1528
batctl if add eth1
ifconfig bat0 192.168.6.6

# Host B
ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1528
batctl if add wlan0
ifconfig bat0 192.168.6.7
ping 192.168.6.6 ## No ping!!!
```

I'm sure the wireless connection is working because I can
ping hosts if I assign ip to wireless interfaces:

```
# Host A
ifconfig eth1 192.168.99.6

# Host B
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.99.7
ping 192.168.99.6 # Ping ok
```

I've tried to setup wireless with `iwconfig` and with `wpa_supplicant` but the result doesn't change.

Any idea?

#### EDIT 1

After some investigations in logs, I've found these interesting lines (host B) repeating:

```
[   7267780] Received BATMAN packet via NB: 90:4c:e5:__:__:__, IF: wlan0 [00:0b:81:__:__:__] (from OG: 90:4c:e5:__:__:__, via prev OG: 90:4c:e5:__:__:__, seqno 2, ttvn 1, crc 53338, changes 1, td 255, TTL 50, V 14, IDF 0)
[   7267780] updating last_seqno: old 1, new 2
[   7267780] bidirectional: orig = 90:4c:e5:__:__:__ neigh = 90:4c:e5:__:__:__ => own_bcast =  0, real recv =  2, local tq:   0, asym_penalty:  24, total tq:   0
[   7267780] Forwarding packet: tq: 0, ttl: 49
[   7267780] Forwarding packet: rebroadcast neighbor packet with direct link flag
```

So... *host B* is receiving something from *host A*! But ping isn't working and `batctl o` says *"No batman nodes in range ..."*

Comment: What wireless card are you using?

Comment: host A: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n, host B: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Comment: Just a guess: it might be that the wi-fi card driver doesn't support some feature needed for BATMAN to work.

Comment: ok, where can I find the list of features BATMAN needs?

Comment: Here: https://lists.open-mesh.org/pipermail/b.a.t.m.a.n/2011-November/005697.html ; this is suggesting you're not the only one with this issue. Reading the whole thread will help you.

Comment: His problem is different, he is trying to connect with a non-batman client to the mesh. To do this he needs two wireless interfaces or two *virtual* interfaces in the same physical network card, that isn't supported by the RTL8188CUS adapter. I'm just creating a simple batman network over adhoc wireless network, so it isn't my case, right?

Comment: His case IS different, but it might need the same driver capabilities you need. Like I said, it's just a guess.